# How to set size of a `cv.Mat()` equal to the size of the video?

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am new to opencv.js and this is how I am setting the size in `opencv.js`:

```
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
let height = video.videoHeight;
let width = video.videoWidth;
console.log(height, width);  // this outputs 480,640

let src = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let dst = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let gray = new cv.Mat();
```

But I am getting the following error at processVideo (app.js:55):

> Error: Bad size of input mat: the size should be the same as the video.

Line 55 in app.js is 
`cap.read(src);`

On checking the size of the matrix **src**, I get the following results:

```
console.log(src.rows); //480
console.log(src.cols); //640
```

which I believe is correct.

Then why am I getting the error? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width and height of the video is a quick fix:

```
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
video.height = video.videoHeight;
video.width = video.videoWidth;
console.log(height, width);  // this outputs 480,640

let src = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let dst = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let gray = new cv.Mat();
```